# Unity3D 5.3, Facebook SDK does not work in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

I want to login into Facebook and share some info. Here is code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;
using System;

public class FBManager : MonoBehaviour {

    void Awake()
    {
        FB.Init(Init);
    }

    void Init()
    {
        Debug.Log("initialized");
    }

    public void Share()
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log("going to call FB.ShareLink()");
            FB.ShareLink(new Uri("http://www.google.com/"), "google", "google super search engine", null,ShareCallback);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("going to call Login()");
            Login();
        }
    }

    private void Login()
    {
        FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(new List<string>() { "publish_actions" }, LoginCallback);
    }

    void LoginCallback(ILoginResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("error: " + result.Error);
        if (result.Error != null)
            Debug.LogError(result.Error);
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("logged? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);
            Share();
        }
    }

    void ShareCallback(IShareResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
            Debug.LogError(result.Error);
        else
            Debug.Log("sharing done");
    }
}
```

And when it calls Login() method it gives an error

> 2015-12-14 17:36:25.910 TheMyAppName[741:307812] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'fb0 is
>   not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist'

How do I fix it? It happens only when I'm making XCODE project with Unity 5.3, in Unity 5.2 all is right.

Answer (score 0):

probably something's wrong with fb Unity sdk. [This is how you integrate FB SDK in iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9). So probably you should manually implement the step 3 in xCode. If it throws another similar error just copy the scheme from the error log and again add it to plist.

Comment: Dude there are so many things wrong with your comment... Just... CMD+Shift+B generates an xCode project :/

Comment: I said that the compiled project is not *readable by humans.*  Yes, it opens in XCode and yes it compiles to iOS.  That doesn't mean that a human can go in and *make changes to the code.*

Comment: I have tried what you said, Nika Kasradze. Unfortunately it does not help =(